# Rigged model won't let me select bones

Tags: bones

On this model of a deer i noticed i can not longer select the bones with right click, i also noticed two bone icons in the Outliner, when i select the one on the right it selects the bones but not the model, and i right click a new bone it selects the mesh instead.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got "Restrict viewport selection" enabled mate. Disable it and you will be able to select bones as usual.I highlighted this option on your image:[image]

And off the topic, you should fix normals on your mesh, by going to Edit mode, selecting all faces and pressing CTRL+N.